# Yesod and MySQL connection issue

Tags: mysql, haskell, yesod

I have been looking for a working example on the web to connect `Yesod` - `Persistent` to a MySQL db, and I found this [resource on GitHub](https://github.com/yesodweb/yesod/wiki/Example-MySQL-Connection-code)

```
{-# LANGUAGE EmptyDataDecls             #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts           #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs                      #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses      #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings          #-}
{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes                #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell            #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies               #-}
import           Control.Monad.IO.Class  (liftIO)
import           Control.Monad.Logger    (runStderrLoggingT)
import           Database.Persist
import           Database.Persist.MySQL
import           Database.Persist.TH

share [mkPersist sqlSettings, mkMigrate "migrateAll"] [persistLowerCase|
Person
    name String
    age Int Maybe
    address Int
    deriving Show
BlogPost
    title String
    authorId PersonId
    deriving Show
|]

connectionInfo = defaultConnectInfo { connectPort = 5000,
                                      connectPassword = "password",
                                      connectDatabase = "database"}

main :: IO ()
main = runStderrLoggingT $ withMySQLPool connectionInfo 10 $ \pool -> liftIO $ do
         flip runSqlPersistMPool pool $ do
           printMigration migrateAll
```

When I try out this code with `ghci` I get the following error:

```
Prelude> :l test3.hs 
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( test3.hs, interpreted )

test3.hs:35:27:
    Couldn't match type `persistent-2.2.2.1:Database.Persist.Sql.Types.SqlBackend'
                  with `SqlBackend'
    Expected type: Migration
      Actual type: persistent-2.2.2.1:Database.Persist.Sql.Types.Migration
    In the first argument of `printMigration', namely `migrateAll'
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: printMigration migrateAll
    In the second argument of `($)', namely
      `do { printMigration migrateAll }'
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

And I got stuck in it.

Another question I have is: Has anybody experience with Yesod + MySQL? If yes, I would like to know if it is a good or a problematic choice.

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

Comment: @RiggsFolly It may be useful for other users, there are very little resources on the web about this.

Comment: Thats fine, 4 other people have to agree with me for the close to be actioned

Comment: One actual question here is: what is the reason of GHC's (a Haskell compiler) error message "cannot match type package-foo:Bar with Bar".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you have two versions of a package installed. If you install with Stack, it will ensure that you have just a single version of each package in scope. I go into some detail on describing this situation in [this blog post](http://www.yesodweb.com/blog/2014/09/woes-multiple-package-versions).